# Allowing only certain resources or process counts for grep or any other such process

Tags: linux, shell, process, limit, ulimit

I have a cron-job(sh file) which greps(ps aux | grep) for certain process every 2 min.
It usually takes  <5 secs to run.

But sometimes back, my server load went to 2400 and I had to manually restart my server to bring everything back to normal.

When I checked my logs, I found that there were hundreds of sh file running at same time and grep processes. Every 2 mins a new sh process was starting and earlier once were hanged in grep process, thus increasing the running count and load.
I couldn't find out exactly what was the reason for grep taking this much time or getting hung.

But to avoid the same thing in future, I am thinking to put some capping limit, on the number of active sh processes or grep process that can run at a time on the server, like I can limit the number of php-sessions in php-fpm.

Is there any way I can do this on linux server?
or any better solution to prevent the same thing happen again?

P.S. : while adding tags,I just came across

> 'ulimit'

may be this is the thing, I am searching for, so added it as well.
Now reading about it,if it could help.

Comment: `ulimit` is the actual choice, but it is not possible to track per `grep` process. `ulimit` sets it for all the processes.

Comment: rather than verbal descriptions, we can only help you fix your problem if you include real evidence of the problem. Include a small test case (code, your script that is causing the problem, crontab entries, etc), and actual output and error messages and people will help. Good luck.